# Unable to find the applicationhost.config to configure remote access in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: iis, remote-access, iis-express, visual-studio-2015

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. Now I just installed Visual Studio 2015. before I developing that project using Visual Studio 2013. So now I imported that project into Visual Studio 2015 installed on my new laptop to continue developing. Importing project and developing process all working fine.

But the problem is to configure IIS Express of my project for remote access. I enabled in Visual Studio 2013 on my old laptop successfully following this link - http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer. For VS 2013, the IIS config file is under  D:\Users[YourName]\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config. So now I need to configure it for VS 2015. As the link mentioned, the config file must be in /{project folder}/.vs/config/applicationhost.config. I searched for that file in my project, I cannot find it.

You can see my project structure below.

[image]

So I searched for config settings in `D:\Users[YourName]\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` because this project was built using VS 2013. But there is no config settings for this project. I already run my project on browser and it is running fine.

The problem is I cannot find binding settings in `D:\Users[YourName]\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` and cannot find applicationhost.config in project folder for IIS configuration. Where can I find that file? Where can I find IIS config settings for my project in Visual Studio 2015?

> .vs/applicationhost.config is not created when I opened the project
>   with visual studio 2015.

Comment: first open your project properties and check in your web section that in which server your project is hosted.(means Visual studio development server or any other server or Local web server if this this running on local web server then check IIS express is cehcked or not ) and let us know.

Comment: It is running on IIS express. I just cannot find the applicationhost.config file to configure remote access.

Comment: Check IIS Express in system tray and go your app config file from there

Comment: .vs is a hidden folder. Change Windows Explorer options to show all hidden folders and you will find it.

Comment: I already tried showing hidden folder. Cannot find. But I solved the problem.

Comment: I already posted the answer. Thank you all for supporting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Please have a look how I solved below.

1. I opened GITIGNORE file as in the below screenshot
   [image]
2. Then I added/appended this line

   .vs/

to that file and saved.

3. Then I restart visual studio and opened the project.

So .vs file is auto-created and applicationhost.config file is inside there. Hope this works for you if you have similar issue.